# Stop Route Group from being processed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using Laravel route groups to call my controllers via api.example.com and www.example.com

```
Route::group(['domain' => Config::get('app.api_server')], function ()
{

    //API entry point

});

Route::group(['domain' => Config::get('app.web_server')], function ()
{
   //Web Application entry point
});
```

However when I make requests to the API all the business logic and database queries in the web application part of the route groups still gets executed which is inefficient and unnecessary for our use case. Same situation vice-versa, going to the web executes all the code inside the API entry point. How can I prevent the irrelevant code from executing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback function closure is executed as part of the call to Route::group(), so there is no way to prevent the callback from executing. You could, however, prevent the routes from being defined in the first place.

```
// only create the api routes if the current request is for the api
if (Request::getHttpHost() == Config::get('app.api_server')) {
    Route::group(['domain' => Config::get('app.api_server')], function ()
    {
        //API entry point
    });
}

// only create the web app routes if the current request is for the web app
if (Request::getHttpHost() == Config::get('app.web_server')) {
    Route::group(['domain' => Config::get('app.web_server')], function ()
    {
       //Web Application entry point
    });
}
```